# “Variability” error in model with function call

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

The following code

```
model FunctionCall
  Boolean result;

  function F
    input Real p1;
    output Boolean result;
  algorithm 
    result :=p1 < 0.5;
  end F;

algorithm 
  result :=F(time);
end FunctionCall;
```

(also described in http://www.modelica-forum.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=2) still throws an error in Dymola 2018FD01, while in OpenModelica it is accepted.
Is this wrong Modelica code or a Dymola bug?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hans answer is the correct one for your question.

Your unasked question may be how one can get the same behavior within the language specifications. Below I have provided one possible solution.

```
model FunctionCall
  Boolean result;

  function F
    input Real p1;
    output Integer result;
  algorithm 
    result := if p1 < 0.5 then 1 else 0;
  end F;

algorithm 

  result := if F(time) < 0.5 then false else true;

end FunctionCall;
```

Comment: Good work-around, but I would use "if F(time) < 0.5 then false else true" instead since each comparison is mapped to a crossing function for the numeric solvers and you want the crossing functions to cross zero - not just touch it. Or in other words the solvers treat "<" and "<=" similarly. (Alternatively use 0, 1,2 instead of 0,0.5,1)

Comment: `not F(time) < 0.5` also should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

The model is incorrect.

3.8 "For an assignment v:=expr or binding equation v=expr, v must be declared to be at least as variable as expr"

Boolean variables are discrete-time expressions according to 3.8.3 "Discrete-time variables, i.e., Integer, Boolean, String variables and enumeration variables, as well as Real variables assigned in when-clauses"

F(time) is not a discrete-time expression, since 3.8.3 only includes "Function calls where all input arguments of the function are discrete-time expressions"

All according to Modelica 3.4.

The reason is that Boolean variables in models should only change at events, and the result of a function such as F(time) can neither guarantee that nor reliably generate events.

Comment: Just as info: the numbers Hans is talking about are chapters in the Modelica Language Specification 3.4 (shipped with Dymola and available on [modelica.org](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But then I do not understand why the workaround described in http://www.modelica-forum.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=2)  works (adding an additional dummy real output).

Comment: That work-around isn't correct either, but a check is currently missing for multi-returning functions.